# Calculating GPS Speed from iOS Location Data

Tags: performance, xamarin.forms, gps

I am having trouble calculating a good speed from GPS location data. I am using Xamarin Forms with Xamarin Essensials. This allow cross platform location data.

The method for collecting the data is a polling method, but I don't think that should be the problem.

I have tried several routines to calculate the distance based on the lat / long values and they all give the same results, so I don't think that is the issue either.

I do wait until I have an accuracy value of at least 10 meters and most of the time I get it at 5 meters of accuracy.

Here is the distance calculation I am using:

```
        public static double GetDistance(Location point1, Location point2)
        {
            double Lat = (point2.Latitude - point1.Latitude) * (Math.PI / 180);
            double Lon = (point2.Longitude - point1.Longitude) * (Math.PI / 180);
            double a = Math.Sin(Lat / 2) * Math.Sin(Lat / 2) + Math.Cos(point1.Latitude * (Math.PI / 180)) * Math.Cos(point2.Latitude * (Math.PI / 180)) * Math.Sin(Lon / 2) * Math.Sin(Lon / 2);
            double c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));
            double distance = 6376500.0 * c;

            return distance;
         }
```

Even when I seem to be getting good data the resulting speed isn't really close to what I am actually seeing. I am walking with 2 iPhones. One is using a GPS speed app from the app store. It usually shows between 1 and 3 MPH.

My app is showing most of the time 0 and then it will suddenly show 14 or 23 or 2 or 6. It seems to bounce all over the place.

Here is my code that calculates everything:

```
        private static Location _previousLatLng;
        private static double _previousSpeed;
        private static List<double> _speedList;
        public static double Speed(Location newLatLng, out double distance, out double time)
        {
            if (_speedList == null)
                _speedList = new List<double>();

            distance = time = 0;

            if (_previousLatLng == null)
            {
                _previousLatLng = newLatLng;
                return 0;
            }

            distance = GetDistance(_previousLatLng, newLatLng);
            time = (newLatLng.Timestamp - _previousLatLng.Timestamp).TotalSeconds;

            _previousLatLng = newLatLng;

            if (time == 0)
                return _previousSpeed;

            _previousSpeed = (distance / time) * 2.237;
            _previousSpeed = Math.Round(_previousSpeed, 0);

            if (_speedList.Count > 0)
            {
                double average = _speedList.Average();
                if (Math.Abs(_previousSpeed - average) < (1 + (average * 0.1)))
                {
                    _speedList.Add(_previousSpeed);
                    if (_speedList.Count > 10)
                        _speedList.RemoveAt(0);

                    _previousSpeed = _speedList.Average();
                }
            }
            else
                _speedList.Add(_previousSpeed);

            return _previousSpeed;
        }
```

Here is how I call it:

```
                                    double distance = 0;
                                    double time = 0;
                                    GPSSpeed = GPSCalculator.Speed(location, out distance, out time);
                                    if (distance > 0 && time > 0)
                                    {
                                        GPSDistance = distance;
                                        GPSTime = time;
                                    }
```

I am sampling the GPS every 100ms. The accuracy during this log was 5meters. Here is some sample output:

```
2021-07-15 15:34:50.463 - Lat: 41.2457532357433 Long: -111.993074229977 Distance: 0 Time: 0.136128
2021-07-15 15:34:50.601 - Lat: 41.2457532357433 Long: -111.993074229977 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1361792
2021-07-15 15:34:50.742 - Lat: 41.2457532357433 Long: -111.993074229977 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1387264
2021-07-15 15:34:50.875 - Lat: 41.2457532357433 Long: -111.993074229977 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1400576
2021-07-15 15:34:51.010 - Lat: 41.2457532357433 Long: -111.993074229977 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1335552
2021-07-15 15:34:51.138 - Lat: 41.2457532357433 Long: -111.993074229977 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1347328
2021-07-15 15:34:51.273 - Lat: 41.2457532357433 Long: -111.993074229977 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1299456
2021-07-15 15:34:51.408 - Lat: 41.2457509409894 Long: -111.993070919767 Distance: 0.376758239904982 Time: 0.1328512
2021-07-15 15:34:51.540 - Lat: 41.2457509409894 Long: -111.993070919767 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1338624
2021-07-15 15:34:51.676 - Lat: 41.2457509409894 Long: -111.993070919767 Distance: 0 Time: 0.132416
2021-07-15 15:34:51.812 - Lat: 41.2457509409894 Long: -111.993070919767 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1365504
2021-07-15 15:34:51.955 - Lat: 41.2457509409894 Long: -111.993070919767 Distance: 0 Time: 0.137024
2021-07-15 15:34:52.091 - Lat: 41.2457509409894 Long: -111.993070919767 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1411072
2021-07-15 15:34:52.226 - Lat: 41.2457509409894 Long: -111.993070919767 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1378688
2021-07-15 15:34:52.360 - Lat: 41.245753890792 Long: -111.993067709261 Distance: 0.424198851848374 Time: 0.1342592
2021-07-15 15:34:52.493 - Lat: 41.245753890792 Long: -111.993067709261 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1322496
2021-07-15 15:34:52.626 - Lat: 41.245753890792 Long: -111.993067709261 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1343616
2021-07-15 15:34:52.762 - Lat: 41.245753890792 Long: -111.993067709261 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1336576
2021-07-15 15:34:52.900 - Lat: 41.245753890792 Long: -111.993067709261 Distance: 0 Time: 0.135488
2021-07-15 15:34:53.041 - Lat: 41.245753890792 Long: -111.993067709261 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1389952
2021-07-15 15:34:53.194 - Lat: 41.245753890792 Long: -111.993067709261 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1406464
2021-07-15 15:34:53.333 - Lat: 41.2457695635164 Long: -111.993054884293 Distance: 2.0479365347566 Time: 0.1507456
2021-07-15 15:34:53.473 - Lat: 41.2457695635164 Long: -111.993054884293 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1399808
2021-07-15 15:34:53.606 - Lat: 41.2457695635164 Long: -111.993054884293 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1386496
2021-07-15 15:34:53.747 - Lat: 41.2457695635164 Long: -111.993054884293 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1359488
2021-07-15 15:34:53.890 - Lat: 41.2457695635164 Long: -111.993054884293 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1401984
2021-07-15 15:34:54.029 - Lat: 41.2457695635164 Long: -111.993054884293 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1431424
2021-07-15 15:34:54.181 - Lat: 41.2457695635164 Long: -111.993054884293 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1388544
2021-07-15 15:34:54.322 - Lat: 41.24578381369 Long: -111.993052633481 Distance: 1.59705971256388 Time: 0.1511936
2021-07-15 15:34:54.459 - Lat: 41.24578381369 Long: -111.993052633481 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1403776
2021-07-15 15:34:54.591 - Lat: 41.24578381369 Long: -111.993052633481 Distance: 0 Time: 0.138624
2021-07-15 15:34:54.730 - Lat: 41.24578381369 Long: -111.993052633481 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1316736
2021-07-15 15:34:54.862 - Lat: 41.24578381369 Long: -111.993052633481 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1392768
2021-07-15 15:34:54.988 - Lat: 41.24578381369 Long: -111.993052633481 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1318784
2021-07-15 15:34:55.120 - Lat: 41.24578381369 Long: -111.993052633481 Distance: 0 Time: 0.125952
2021-07-15 15:34:55.252 - Lat: 41.24578381369 Long: -111.993052633481 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1322368
2021-07-15 15:34:55.388 - Lat: 41.2457951287642 Long: -111.993058403988 Distance: 1.34866912642065 Time: 0.1321984
2021-07-15 15:34:55.528 - Lat: 41.2457951287642 Long: -111.993058403988 Distance: 0 Time: 0.13408
2021-07-15 15:34:55.668 - Lat: 41.2457951287642 Long: -111.993058403988 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1410688
2021-07-15 15:34:55.807 - Lat: 41.2457951287642 Long: -111.993058403988 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1406848
2021-07-15 15:34:55.949 - Lat: 41.2457951287642 Long: -111.993058403988 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1387136
2021-07-15 15:34:56.094 - Lat: 41.2457951287642 Long: -111.993058403988 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1421824
2021-07-15 15:34:56.223 - Lat: 41.2457951287642 Long: -111.993058403988 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1446272
2021-07-15 15:34:56.352 - Lat: 41.2458014067289 Long: -111.993060079922 Distance: 0.712615929386394 Time: 0.1293952
2021-07-15 15:34:56.483 - Lat: 41.2458014067289 Long: -111.993060079922 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1277312
2021-07-15 15:34:56.624 - Lat: 41.2458014067289 Long: -111.993060079922 Distance: 0 Time: 0.132096
2021-07-15 15:34:56.749 - Lat: 41.2458014067289 Long: -111.993060079922 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1411456
2021-07-15 15:34:56.890 - Lat: 41.2458014067289 Long: -111.993060079922 Distance: 0 Time: 0.125696
2021-07-15 15:34:57.029 - Lat: 41.2458014067289 Long: -111.993060079922 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1403648
2021-07-15 15:34:57.176 - Lat: 41.2458014067289 Long: -111.993060079922 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1395328
2021-07-15 15:34:57.315 - Lat: 41.2458099550849 Long: -111.993061225149 Distance: 0.956168757912261 Time: 0.1456512
2021-07-15 15:34:57.453 - Lat: 41.2458099550849 Long: -111.993061225149 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1388032
2021-07-15 15:34:57.594 - Lat: 41.2458099550849 Long: -111.993061225149 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1382784
2021-07-15 15:34:57.736 - Lat: 41.2458099550849 Long: -111.993061225149 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1413888
2021-07-15 15:34:57.878 - Lat: 41.2458099550849 Long: -111.993061225149 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1421824
2021-07-15 15:34:58.018 - Lat: 41.2458099550849 Long: -111.993061225149 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1420544
2021-07-15 15:34:58.159 - Lat: 41.2458099550849 Long: -111.993061225149 Distance: 0 Time: 0.139712
2021-07-15 15:34:58.300 - Lat: 41.2458224263884 Long: -111.993064427178 Distance: 1.41356902824941 Time: 0.141568
2021-07-15 15:34:58.435 - Lat: 41.2458224263884 Long: -111.993064427178 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1401216
2021-07-15 15:34:58.574 - Lat: 41.2458224263884 Long: -111.993064427178 Distance: 0 Time: 0.135104
2021-07-15 15:34:58.709 - Lat: 41.2458224263884 Long: -111.993064427178 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1399552
2021-07-15 15:34:58.845 - Lat: 41.2458224263884 Long: -111.993064427178 Distance: 0 Time: 0.134848
2021-07-15 15:34:58.985 - Lat: 41.2458224263884 Long: -111.993064427178 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1358976
2021-07-15 15:34:59.118 - Lat: 41.2458224263884 Long: -111.993064427178 Distance: 0 Time: 0.139968
2021-07-15 15:34:59.246 - Lat: 41.2458224263884 Long: -111.993064427178 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1331072
2021-07-15 15:34:59.374 - Lat: 41.2458378412934 Long: -111.993073872658 Distance: 1.88885597475969 Time: 0.1271296
2021-07-15 15:34:59.499 - Lat: 41.2458378412934 Long: -111.993073872658 Distance: 0 Time: 0.126144
2021-07-15 15:34:59.626 - Lat: 41.2458378412934 Long: -111.993073872658 Distance: 0 Time: 0.126784
2021-07-15 15:34:59.757 - Lat: 41.2458378412934 Long: -111.993073872658 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1273856
2021-07-15 15:34:59.874 - Lat: 41.2458378412934 Long: -111.993073872658 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1304704
2021-07-15 15:35:00.007 - Lat: 41.2458378412934 Long: -111.993073872658 Distance: 0 Time: 0.118464
2021-07-15 15:35:00.140 - Lat: 41.2458378412934 Long: -111.993073872658 Distance: 0 Time: 0.132032
2021-07-15 15:35:00.271 - Lat: 41.2458378412934 Long: -111.993073872658 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1307136
2021-07-15 15:35:00.406 - Lat: 41.2458531355872 Long: -111.993085496848 Distance: 1.96044097014122 Time: 0.133568
2021-07-15 15:35:00.544 - Lat: 41.2458531355872 Long: -111.993085496848 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1325568
2021-07-15 15:35:00.680 - Lat: 41.2458531355872 Long: -111.993085496848 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1394944
2021-07-15 15:35:00.809 - Lat: 41.2458531355872 Long: -111.993085496848 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1365504
2021-07-15 15:35:00.946 - Lat: 41.2458531355872 Long: -111.993085496848 Distance: 0 Time: 0.129536
2021-07-15 15:35:01.085 - Lat: 41.2458531355872 Long: -111.993085496848 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1375616
2021-07-15 15:35:01.220 - Lat: 41.2458531355872 Long: -111.993085496848 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1389056
2021-07-15 15:35:01.353 - Lat: 41.2458613614931 Long: -111.99309472014 Distance: 1.19738920232849 Time: 0.1346304
2021-07-15 15:35:01.487 - Lat: 41.2458613614931 Long: -111.99309472014 Distance: 0 Time: 0.131648
2021-07-15 15:35:01.629 - Lat: 41.2458613614931 Long: -111.99309472014 Distance: 0 Time: 0.134976
2021-07-15 15:35:01.775 - Lat: 41.2458613614931 Long: -111.99309472014 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1415936
2021-07-15 15:35:01.914 - Lat: 41.2458613614931 Long: -111.99309472014 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1453184
2021-07-15 15:35:02.049 - Lat: 41.2458613614931 Long: -111.99309472014 Distance: 0 Time: 0.14016
2021-07-15 15:35:02.187 - Lat: 41.2458613614931 Long: -111.99309472014 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1355392
2021-07-15 15:35:02.328 - Lat: 41.2458776258745 Long: -111.993110671499 Distance: 2.24900513250483 Time: 0.1378432
2021-07-15 15:35:02.464 - Lat: 41.2458776258745 Long: -111.993110671499 Distance: 0 Time: 0.13984
2021-07-15 15:35:02.606 - Lat: 41.2458776258745 Long: -111.993110671499 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1362688
2021-07-15 15:35:02.744 - Lat: 41.2458776258745 Long: -111.993110671499 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1428608
2021-07-15 15:35:02.887 - Lat: 41.2458776258745 Long: -111.993110671499 Distance: 0 Time: 0.137984
2021-07-15 15:35:03.029 - Lat: 41.2458776258745 Long: -111.993110671499 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1431936
2021-07-15 15:35:03.179 - Lat: 41.2458776258745 Long: -111.993110671499 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1422336
2021-07-15 15:35:03.315 - Lat: 41.2458905069283 Long: -111.993112112671 Distance: 1.43860780807483 Time: 0.1496576
2021-07-15 15:35:03.447 - Lat: 41.2458905069283 Long: -111.993112112671 Distance: 0 Time: 0.134144
2021-07-15 15:35:03.587 - Lat: 41.2458905069283 Long: -111.993112112671 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1331328
2021-07-15 15:35:03.731 - Lat: 41.2458905069283 Long: -111.993112112671 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1406464
2021-07-15 15:35:03.872 - Lat: 41.2458905069283 Long: -111.993112112671 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1434624
2021-07-15 15:35:04.013 - Lat: 41.2458905069283 Long: -111.993112112671 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1412864
2021-07-15 15:35:04.159 - Lat: 41.2458905069283 Long: -111.993112112671 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1410432
2021-07-15 15:35:04.301 - Lat: 41.2459160810984 Long: -111.993127567139 Distance: 3.12619120355082 Time: 0.146048
2021-07-15 15:35:04.441 - Lat: 41.2459160810984 Long: -111.993127567139 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1410048
2021-07-15 15:35:04.579 - Lat: 41.2459160810984 Long: -111.993127567139 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1405952
2021-07-15 15:35:04.725 - Lat: 41.2459160810984 Long: -111.993127567139 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1391104
2021-07-15 15:35:04.864 - Lat: 41.2459160810984 Long: -111.993127567139 Distance: 0 Time: 0.144832
2021-07-15 15:35:05.006 - Lat: 41.2459160810984 Long: -111.993127567139 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1392384
2021-07-15 15:35:05.139 - Lat: 41.2459160810984 Long: -111.993127567139 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1428992
2021-07-15 15:35:05.271 - Lat: 41.2459160810984 Long: -111.993127567139 Distance: 0 Time: 0.1326208
```

Comment: I would guess that the other app is not doing an instantaneous point-to-point calculation, but is instead using some sort of rolling average.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796157/best-practice-to-calculate-the-average-speed-from-gps-coordinates or https://www.google.com/search?q=calculating+walking+speed+using+gps+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment. My code is already averaging the speed value and even throwing out ones that are really different. Maybe I just need to average a much larger sample. My main question is why don't the main samples themselves seem to be anywhere close to my actual speed? None of the instant samples are even close. Most of them are 0, so that is my main question. I can't just throw out all 0 samples in case the user is actually standing still. So that is my question. How do I know if a sample is one to keep or throw away?

Comment: I think I might have figured it out. As I took a closer look I noticed that main samples had the exact same lat / long. I then realized that the chances of having the exactly same value is pretty slim given the nature of GPS always taking a new reading. I then added code to discard all values that matched the previous lat / long exactly. After doing that I found that even though the GPS was giving "new" samples as often as I asked, there were really only new samples about once per second. So when I throw out all of those same samples I get the readings I am after. Thanks for your help...

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, please add an "Answer" below, describing the solution. This will let everyone know that there is an answer. After 48 hours, if no one has provided an answer you think is even better, then please "Accept" your own answer. (You won't be able to Accept before 48 hours.)

Answer (score 0):

Because GPS "bounces around" a lot, it **isn't reliable** to **compute speed** between successive **position** samples,

Instead, use the built-in solution:

[Xamarin.Essentials Location.Speed Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.location.speed?view=xamarin-essentials).

---

If that value still "bounces around" more than is satisfactory, then apply some "smoothing" to the sequence of values.

A simple smoothing would be:

```
smoothedSpeed[i] = k*speed[i-1] + k*speed[i+1] + (1-2*k)*speed[i];
```

Where `k` is usually a value between `0` and `0.333`. `0` is "no smoothing", `0.333` is "maximum smoothing". If not sure, start with `0.1`. This will somewhat smooth the jumpiness, without overly changing the maximum speed seen. Record sample data, and plot it at several different `k`s: `0`, `0.05`, `0.1`, `0.2`, `0.333`. Its a trade-off: decide which you prefer.

If you need an instantaneous answer, so sample `[i+1]` isn't available yet, then the best you can do is:

```
smoothedSpeed[i] = k*speed[i-1] + (1-k)*speed[i];
```

Its also possible to smooth in a smaller amount of sample `[i-2]`, etc. Use a multiplier `k2` for second sample, that is no more than half of `k` - you want more distant samples to have only a small effect.

Regardless, the `sum of "weights"` must always be exactly `1`, so that you don't accidentally raise or lower the average speed. Below, `k2+k+(1-k-k2)` = `1`.

```
.. = k2*speed[i-2] + k*speed[i-1] + (1-k-k2)*speed[i];
```

This works best if you've filtered-OR-interpolated samples, so they occur at a regular interval. That is, the time between successive samples (that you are averaging) should be the same,